# After capturing a layout screenshot, ImageView is transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem in Android screen capture. The captured image is transparent while the original image is solid JPEG file which is not transparent!
I tested in on many devices with different OS version and problem persists on all phones.
Here is my code for screen capture and also the final output

Code:

```
final Bitmap rawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(rawBitmap);
rendererView.layout(0, 0, width, height);
rendererView.draw(canvas);
rawBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/test" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png"));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Provide details of the device, os version.

Comment: I think the problem persists in all OS versions and All manufacture and brands! The application tested on 2.1, 2.2, 4.0, 4.1 and on HTC, Samsung, Sony Ericsson

Comment: I would try to save to `CompressFormat.JPEG` (it will eliminate the transparency).  Also, what kind of object is `rendererView` ?

Comment: Yes, Absolutely saving to JPEG will eliminate the transparency. But I want translucent pixels when a pixel is transparent really. Also I want translucent pixels when nothing rendered in UI ( like empty margin that has no widget ). The rendererView is just a simple FrameLayout that contain UI widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was solved. When loading image source to ImageView, I used wrong setting for BitmapFactory Options.

The Code ( Before And After ):

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    //options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_4444; //WRONG
    options.inPreferredConfig = Config.ARGB_8888; //CORRECT
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(result.filePath(), options);
```

Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

I would try Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 in createBitmap()

Comment: Alpha is required to hold pixels that is transparent really. So RGB_565 that hasn't alpha and make some quality lose is not a good answer.